# Alexa "I'm not quite sure what went wrong."

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-smart-home-skill

I am having problems with a smart home skill. The discovery part seems to go well but when I try to report state the following happens.

My smart home skill sends this request

```
{
    "directive": {
        "header": {
            "namespace":"Alexa",
            "name":"ReportState",
            "payloadVersion":"3",
            "messageId":"[ID]",
            "correlationToken":"[Token]"
        },
        "endpoint": {
            "scope": {
                "type":"BearerToken",
                "token":"[AuthToken]"
            },
            "endpointId":"appliance-002",
            "cookie": {}
        },
        "payload": {}
    }
}
```

I return this

```
{
    "context": {
        "properties": [
            {
                "namespace":"Alexa.TemperatureSensor",
                "name":"temperature",
                "timeOfSample":"2018-04-08T20:44:33Z",
                "uncertaintyInMilliseconds":500,
                "value": {
                    "value":23,
                    "scale":"CELSIUS"
                }
            },
            {
                "namespace":"Alexa.EndpointHealth",
                "name":"connectivity",
                "timeOfSample":"2018-04-08T20:44:33Z",
                "uncertaintyInMilliseconds":0,
                "value":"OK"
            }
        ]
    },
    "event": {
        "header": {
            "namespace":"Alexa",
            "name":"StateReport",
            "payloadVersion":"3",
            "messageId":"[ID]",
            "correlationToken":"[Token]"
        },
        "endpoint": {
            "endpointId":"appliance-002",
            "cookie": {},
            "scope": {
                "type":"BearerToken",
                "token":"[AuthToken]"
            }
        },
        "payload": {}
    }
}
```

And Alexa just say

"I'm not quite sure what went wrong."

Well neither am I. Can anybody figure out whats going on here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Never mind... Figured out that a process downstream altered my json... Nothing like a good nights sleep and a strong cup of coffee to clear the mind.

Answer (score 0):

A process downstream altered my json giving a incomplete response. I am unable to see this in any logs anywhere, so the finding was made by utilizing sleep, coffee and hard work.